# Rustup: how to add/build components for custom toolchain

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

I need to build a repo using a custom toolchain. However, that repo requires

```
rust-src rustc-dev llvm-tools-preview
```

However, it seems rustup can't install components for custom toolchains(correct me if I'm wrong).

Do you know how can I install them or build them by myself?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but I think they are just the proper directories/links in the custom toolchain directory. Particularly for the `rust-src` I just created a symlink in `.rustup/toolchains/mytoolchain/lib/rustlib/src` that points to where the source repository is. I'm guessing that the other components are similar.

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks, yes I can find rust-src in the `./x.py install`, however, for other 2 components I can find them. Even I tried `./x.py install compiler/rustc`, it seems it's not the component we want.

Comment: I tried adding with `rustup` the rustc-dev component  to my beta channel and it created the directory `.rustup/toolchains/beta*/lib/rustlib/rustc-src` plus a bunch of libraries in `.rustup/toolchains/beta*/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/*` and a corresponding manifest. The `llvm-tools-preview` installs the llvm binaries/library into `.rustup/toolchains/beta*/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/{bin,lib}/*`. But I don't know if the `x.py` has a subcommand for installing those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct workflow is:

1. build & install your custom toolchain to a folder.
2. run `./x.py dist`, then you can get many compressed components in the `build/dist` folder.
3. select the component you want and decompress it, there is an `install.sh` script, you can use that script to install the component to your custom toolchain. One example of mine is `./install.sh --prefix=~/rust_custom --components=rustc-dev`, suppose I installed my toolchain in `~/rust_custom` folder.

P.S.

It seems `x.py` doesn't have an install command for the `llvm-tools`, so at least this component needs to be installed manually for a custom toolchain.